# How to put ++var in heredoc string

Tags: php, operators, heredoc

I have heredoc string and I want to put the `++$var` into the string. My code is actually much more complicated, but it simply looks like this:

```
t=0;
for(i=1;i<=20;i++){
echo <<<EOT
{++$t} somestring {$i}
{++$t} otherstring {$i}
{++$t} anotherstring {$i}
{++$t} nextstring {$i}
{++$t} endstring {$i}
EOT;
}
```

In for loop is numbered list with 5 lines, which are continuously repeated. And each 5 lines contain the same number `$i` from the loop. But the `++$t` can't work this way. Any idea how to make it run?

Expected output:

```
1 somestring 1
2 otherstring 1
3 anotherstring 1
4 nextstring 1
5 endstring 1
6 somestring 2
7 otherstring 2
8 anotherstring 2
9 nextstring 2
10 endstring 2
11 somestring 3
...
```

**Update (thanks for responses):**
There is no solution with heredoc. Better to use string concatenation and quotes. If there is a long text within heredoc field, best way is to use array for it.

Comment: Not possible. Can you try, `$array = ['somestring', 'otherstring', 'anotherstring' ...];` and then for through the loop, `echo ++$t . ' ' . $string . ' ' . $i;`.

Comment: Your solution has not so many concatenationing and works better than heredoc in my case. I think, I'll try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a concat method instead:

```
<?php

$array = array(
    'somestring',
    'otherstring',
    'anotherstring',
    'nextstring',
    'endstring'
);

$count = 0;
for ($i2 = 1; $i2 <= 20; $i2++)
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++)
        echo ++$count . ' ' . $array[$i] . ' ' . $i2 . "\n";
```

[Output](http://codepad.org/ePCOmvm4):

```
1 somestring 1
2 otherstring 1
3 anotherstring 1
4 nextstring 1
5 endstring 1
6 somestring 2
7 otherstring 2
8 anotherstring 2
9 nextstring 2
10 endstring 2
11 somestring 3
[..truncated...]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't write expressions inside heredoc style, you can just print variables without any additional operation.

Comment: And can I add before heredoc this line: `$var=++$i;` and in heredoc print `$var`? Does this replacement work?

Comment: No, you need to use single or double quotes.

Comment: Or can I just add before heredoc this line: `$var=$i+1;` and in heredoc print `$var`? Is there any other possibility, how to do that?